# What is Texlive?

Tags: texlive, installing, tools, tlmgr, distributions

I’ve looked on the internet for multiple hours, but I can’t get my head around it.

How to install new packages in the Texlive distribution?

I figured out that there was a package manager for this "distribution", but even the fact of calling it a distribution confuses me.

What is Texlive? How can it be a distribution? How does it work?

Sorry for these silly questions. Bear in mind, I am just starting off with LaTex.

Any kind of explanation would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. TeXLive is one of several TeX distributions. Do you know what a TeX didtribution is?

Comment: @Mico Isn’t Texlive a TeX distribution? If not, then I don’t know what it is.

Comment: I *stated*: "TeXLive is one of several TeX distributions". So why do you ask, "Isn't Texlive a TeX distribution?" (Aside: there are several TeX distributions; TeXLive is just one of them.) The reason I *asked* if you knew what a TeX di[s]tribution was is that much of your query would appear to pertain to TeX distributions in general, not just TeXLive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## TeX involves potentially a lot of software

TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related systems include core programs (executables that call particular formats) and a huge ecosystem of packages, from really essential tools like `graphicx` to more esoteric packages like typesetting chess boards, or ducks with different costumes. All of that stuff, the old, the new, the obsolete, and the indispensable, is all hosted on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org).

## You can get everything you need wrapped together through TeXLive

A very large selection of those things whose licenses allow them to be made freely available, are made available together through the TeXlive distribution hosted through the [TeX User's Group](http://www.tug.org). The system was designed from an earlier, lower-bandwidth era, as a way of distributing a complete TeX software system to TUG members on a set of DVDs. Now anyone can just download it directly.

There are several ways to acquire the [TeXLive](https://tug.org/texlive/) distribution depending on your system and your needs. Many of us on Linux download an installer program, which in turn downloads as much of the distribution as we request in the setup options. You can get absolutely everything or a more minimal distribution.

Once it's all set up, you can use the `tlmgr` tool to update it, or to install extra packages that you didn't add already. (MikTeX is another way to do it just for Windows, and for Mac users there is MacTeX.)

### But don't bother with Linux distribution packaging of TeXLive

The Linux distributions also provide their own, independent wrappers around software from the TeXLive distribution, but each one is different in what it includes and how recent the versions are. On Debian, for example, the software you get this way is can be two years old or more, but that's typical for that distro generally. I think most frequent users of this site would discourage you from getting TeX through the Linux package managers. I've tried it and it's a mess.

## Do you really need all that stuff just to run LaTeX?

Many people have asked why the distribution is so big (and always expanding), and why it can't be simpler to get "just LaTeX." Well, you can download a very small minimal distribution if you want, but as soon as you start wanting to customize things or do more specialized tasks, you will find you need more packages, more fonts, more tools. Few of these packages are essential for *every* user, but it's hard to imagine a user who doesn't need a lot of them. For me it has always just been easier to install the full TeXLive distribution and then I have all my options open. And storage space is pretty cheap these days.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very clear and concise answer! Really helps.